# Magento: images disappear when creating a new product

Tags: magento

I’m using Magento 1.6.1.0,.

When I want to create a new product, I can upload the images, but when I save the product, the images I uploaded are gone, as if I had never uploaded them…

I upgraded Magento from 1.3.2.4 to 1.6.1.0 and the products already loaded show their images fine.

Anyone knows whats going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You uploaded a product image, but did you set the `Base Image`,`Small Image` and `Large Image` radio buttons  and saved for that uploaded image?

Answer (score 0):

You must save configuration after uploading images, and also make sure that remove checkbox is unchecked when you save configuration.